# Hoist pressed state in Jetpack Compose Beta 1 after InteractionState was removed

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Until compose-beta01 it was very easy to hoist the pressed state in Jetpack Compose using `InteractionState`:

```
@Composable
fun App() {
    val interactionState = remember { InteractionState() }
    val pressed = interactionState.contains(Interaction.Pressed)

    MyComposable(Modifier.clickable(interactionState = interactionState) { })
}
```

InteractionState was removed in beta01 and there is now obvious way to replicate this behaviour. How can I hoist the pressed state using the `clickable` modifier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried applying what's explained in the release notes of [Compose beta01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-animation#1.0.0-beta01)?

> `InteractionState` has been replaced with `[Mutable]InteractionSource`
>
> - Interfaces are responsible for emitting / collecting Interaction events.
> - Instead of passing `interactionState = remember { InteractionState() }` to components such as `Button` and `Modifier.clickable()`, use
>   `interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }`.
> - Instead of: `Interaction.Pressed in interactionState` you should instead use the extension functions on InteractionSource, such as
>   InteractionSource.collectIsPressedAsState().
> - For complex use cases you can use InteractionSource.interactions to observe the stream of Interactions. See the InteractionSource
>   documentation and samples for more information.
> - ([I85965](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/q/I85965d0dba39d1740c097915d1d1a367eea2a78c), [b/152525426](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/152525426), [b/171913923](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171913923), [b/171710801](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171710801), [b/174852378](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174852378))

So, in your example, I would try something like:

```
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
val pressedState = interactionSource.collectIsPressedAsState()

MyComposable(
    Modifier.clickable(
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        indication = LocalIndication.current
    ) {}
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Interestingly it only works with `clickable` and not with `combinedClickable`. Is that intended?

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work with `combinedClick`?

Comment: In my case `interactionSource.collectIsPressedState` only changes the state to true and not changes back to false when pressed is released. I cannot reproduce this behavior on a simple example. The issue doesn't occur when using `clickable` instead of `combionedClick`. Probably a bug.

Comment: Based on the documentation of `interactionSource` on both `clickable` and `combinedClickable`, I would say that it's on purpose: "@param interactionSource [MutableInteractionSource] that will be used to dispatch [PressInteraction.Press] when this clickable is pressed. Only the initial (first) press will be recorded and dispatched with [MutableInteractionSource].".

Comment: I also read that, but it doesn't explaing why the behavior is sometimes different on `clickable` compared to `combinedClickable`. Also, the documentation of `collectIsPressedAsState()` states: "[...] return[s] State representing whether this component is being pressed or not". I understand that means it has to be updated